# Remove Duplicate Namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xml-namespaces

So, I am trying to write out this:

```
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
...
    <w:rPr xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
        <w:shadow />
        <p2:u p2:val="dottedHeavy" p2:color="00CCFF" xmlns:p2="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" />
        <p2:effect p2:val="lights" xmlns:p2="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" />
        <p3:caps p3:val="true" xmlns:p3="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" />
    </w:rPr>
...
</w:document>
```

As this

```
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
...
    <w:rPr>
        <w:caps/>
        <w:shadow/>
        <w:u w:color="00CCFF" w:val="dottedHeavy"/>
        <w:effect w:val="lights"/>
    </w:rPr>
...
</w:document>
```

using `xdoc.Save(file, SaveOptions.OmitDuplicateNamespaces)`, but the resulting file still has duplicate namespaces. Since that isn't working, how does one remove duplicate name-spaces from an XDocument? I have tried using `XmlReader`, `XmlWriter`, and `XmlDocument` with their equivalent options, and it still doesn't work.

P.S. in-case you are wondering, that is docx data with `...` representing excluded data

Comment: You need to build XML more carefully... [OmitDuplicateNamespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.saveoptions%28VS.95%29.aspx) not going to help you since prefixes don't match. Alternatively you may write code that clones XML and remaps prefixes if needed. Side note: I don't think having different prefixes should be a problem for DOCX format ...

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was using the idea of make the element, set values, add element to parent pattern thing.

Comment: Have you considered using Xslt to transform your xml document to look the way you want?

Comment: This really seems like `OmitDuplicateNamespaces` is broken.